# Is a measurable set A exploitable by compact sets?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let A be a Lebesgue-measurbale subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. How can I prove that I might exhaust the whole set by let's say cuboids ([this is what I mean by exhaustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_exhaustion)). I know for open sets that we can find a cover out of closed cuboids with disjoint inner areas.

I thought since every Lebesgue-measurable set is composed of a Borel-set and Null-set we might  be able to approximate the set A by open sets which we might cover with countable many cuboids.

But I have no ideawhether that works. What do you think?

Comment: What does it mean to "exploit" a set by cuboids?

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of regularity. Given a Lebesgue-measurable set $A$:

- If $A$ is bounded, we're done (since our approximating closed set will also be bounded, hence compact).
- If $A$ is not bounded, we break it into bounded pieces. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $$A_n=\{a\in A: \Vert a\Vert<n\}$$ be the part of $A$ lying within $n$ of the origin. Given $\epsilon>0$, we iteratively apply regularity to get compact sets $C_n$ such that for each $n$, $C_n\subseteq A_n$ and $\mu(C_n\setminus A_n)<{\epsilon\over 2^{n+1}}$. The family $\{C_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ exhausts $A$ as desired (by countable additivity).